# How to pass and use extras in navigateByUrl() in angular 11?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am passing data with navigateByUrl method and want to access this inside the target components ngOnInit().

this._router.navigateByUrl(`${baseUrl}?${previousFilter}`, { state: {from:'details-page'} });

I am passing data as shown above. So how to I access this state value ngOnInit() of my target compoenent? (using ActiatedRoute or any other standard method).

Which is right way to achieve to this with navigateByUrl()

Answer (score 1):

According to the angular docs, you can achieve this task using the ActivatedRoute API.

In their docs you can find this example, which is very similar to what you are doing:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const heroId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}

gotoItems(hero: Hero) {
  const heroId = hero ? hero.id : null;
  // Pass along the hero id if available
  // so that the HeroList component can select that item.
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId }]);
}
```

Comment: I want it using navigateByUrl() method. And  I want to passs extras data not query params.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use param, you can do like this

```js
const routes = [{
   path: 'user',
   component: UserComponent,
   children: [{
     path: ':username',
     component: UserDetailComponent
   },{
     path: ':username/setting',
     component: UserSettingComponent
   }]
}]
```

```js
class AComponent {
   username = 'yourname';

   constructor(
     private readonly router: Router
   ) {}

   goPage() {
     this.router.navigate([`user/${username}`])
   }

   goPageWithQueryParams() {
     this.router.navigate([`user/${username}`, {
       another: 'another'
     }])
   }
}
```

```js
class BComponent {
   constructor(private readonly acticatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((param) => {
        console.log(param)
     })
   }
}
```